# Display down menu when click toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css

My menu displays down, but then horizontally.

I'd like that every nav-item display down, on top each other.

URL of LIVE testing site: [ministerios-elim.herokuapp.com](http://ministerios-elim.herokuapp.com)

[image]

**CODEPEN:** (Couldn't make the menu appear on click on CodePen).

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/abNQXLg

```
    <header>
    <!--MENU SUPERIOR-->
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top"
        style="height: 70px; padding-top: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%;" id="top-navbar">
        <div class="container">
           
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-link mt-2">
                        <a href="/">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="/doctrina/" class="nav-link mt-3" >Doctrina</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="/iglesias/" class="nav-link mt-3" >Iglesias</a>
                    </li>
                    

                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
                    
                    <span class="text-white">Hola, ogonzales.</span>
                    <a href="/salir/" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Salir</a>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**Update 2:**

[image]

**Update 3:**

```
#navbarCollapse ul li {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have modified html,css and have written a comment on the part where the modification was made /* start update */ /* end update */ - i hope this is useful

```css
/* start update */
nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #navbarCollapse ul li {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #navbarCollapse ul {padding-top:10px}
  #navbarCollapse ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  nav {position: relative}
  nav form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 15px;
  }
}

/* end update */
```

```html
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>
    Ministerios Elim - Inicio

  </title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://universidad-elim-test-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/css/mysite.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://universidad-elim-test-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/css/fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://universidad-elim-test-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/css/banners.css">

</head>

<body class="">

  <header>
    <!--MENU SUPERIOR-->
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <!-- start update -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top" id="top-navbar">
      <div class="container">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-link mt-2">
              <a href="/">Inicio</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/doctrina/" class="nav-link mt-3">Doctrina</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/iglesias/" class="nav-link mt-3">Iglesias</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline ml-auto">

            Hola,
            <a href="/ingresar/" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Ingresar</a>
            <a href="/registrarse/" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Registro</a>

          </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end update -->
  </header>

  <div class="" style="margin-top: 5%;">

    <div id="header">
      <!-- flex container -->

      <div class="box" style="margin-left: 0%;">
        <!-- flex item -->
        <div class="title">
          <div>ELIM</div>
          <div>ONLINE</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box green_strips">
        <!-- flex item -->
        <div style="background-color: black; padding: 0.001em">
          <p style="color: white; margin-top: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 0em;">EXPANDIENDO
            <span class="yellowgreen">LA PALABRA DE DIOS</span></p>
          <p style="color: white; margin-top: 0em;">POR TODO EL <span class="yellowgreen">MUNDO</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="padding-top: 3%;">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="comp-iq9y0o3iiFrameHolder" class="htco1iFrameHolder embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" name="htmlComp-iframe" scrolling="no" src="https://www-ministerioselimlosangeles-net.filesusr.com/html/c6c2ba_7e10543906cc3e0dfef547110eb63f30.html">
            </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" id="LocalSide">

          <h1>PROGRAMACIÓN EN VIVO</h1>
          <p>Martes, viernes y sábados: 7:30 p.m. PDT</p>
          <p>Domingos: 12:30 p.m. PDT</p>
          <p>Escoge tu Conexión Preferida</p>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row ofrendas_y_diezmo_contenedor">
      <div class="box">
        <span class="ofrendas_y_diezmos"> Diezmar y ofrendar</span><br>
        <div class="en_linea_y_desde_tu_movil_contenedor">
          <span class="en_linea_y_desde_tu_movil">Ahora lo puedes hacer en línea y desde tu móvil.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <style type="text/css">
          .tg {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
          }

          .tg td {
            border-color: black;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            word-break: normal;
          }

          .tg th {
            border-color: black;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            word-break: normal;
          }

          .tg .tg-0lax {
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top
          }
        </style>
        <table class="tg">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <a href="https://secure.subsplash.com/ui/access/876ZZX/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" target="_blank">Paypal</a>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <a href="https://secure.subsplash.com/ui/access/876ZZX/" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" target="_blank">SUBSPLASH</a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Usando Zelle $ al 323-490-9435</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer" style="padding-top: 5%;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Próximos servicios:</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="padding-top: 4%;">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Martes</th>
                <th scope="col">Viernes</th>
                <th scope="col">Sábados</th>
                <th scope="col">Domingos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>7:30 p. m.</td>
                <td>7:30 p. m.</td>
                <td>7:30 p. m.</td>
                <td>12:30 p. m.</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div style="padding-left: 20%; padding-top: 15%;">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>8400 S Hoover St, Los Ángeles, CA 90044 | (323) 789-1665</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8b3cda2e27.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://universidad-elim-test-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/js/mysite.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Em An. I've made the changes and pushed to Heroku so you can see the site live. Somehow, navitems render inside navbar, but not one on top of the other. 

What am I missing? https://ministerios-elim.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Take the css that I wrote for you, you haven't taken it yet!

Answer (score 0):

To get it vertically - just add one line of CSS:

```
#navbarCollapse ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I guess it's cache (probably amazon, maybe also w3tc if you have), because elements on front **does not have display: block**, pls see attached:
[image]

Comment: Ty but not working. You can acces the css (mysite.css) in live site at: https://ministerios-elim.herokuapp.com/

Comment: add !important to the end, i.e. `#navbarCollapse ul li {display: block !important;}`

Comment: hm, actually I'm not see `display: block` in css on your site

Comment: please, see my update 2. I'll try adding the important part.

Comment: Ivan, adding important affects not only the mobile view, but the desktop view of the page. Please, see update 3.

Comment: I see display: block now, but there are no **!importnat** because amazon cached it. please open your site in incognito and you will be surprised.
and you can to wait 30 minutes - and important will be applied...

Comment: another thing: if you want this fixes for mobile only - pls use it inside media, i.e.
`@media (max-width: 768px) { #navbarCollapse ul li {display: block !important;} }`